# How to set the height of the colorbox larger than the browser's (screen) height?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

Tried to set the colorbox height larger than the browser (screen) height like 2000px "?width=500&height=2000px", but the colorbox keeps on setting its height not larger than the browser (screen) height.

How to get the height of the colorbox to be larger than the browser (screen) height?

Answer (score 0):

It should be larger by default unless you have set the maxWidth and maxHeight.  You probably want to check to see what your defaults are set to (maxWidth and maxHeight should be set to false by default).